# Group by on Month in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I want group by the result data of oracle database. And also I got the result but the result is groupped as month start to next month start.

I need group by from month start to month end.

"GROUP BY TO_CHAR(COL_DATE,'MON-YYYY')"

As I am getting data from 01-Feb-2018 to 01-Mar-2018.
Required data from 01-Feb-2018 to 28-Feb-2018.

Comment: Please include your current query, and maybe some data.  Without that, I'm not sure we can give you a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the TRUNC function.

the following example shows the number of entries per month

```
SELECT TRUNC(COL_DATE, 'MONTH') AS MONTH, COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY TRUNC(COL_DATE, 'MONTH');
```

Comment: That's irrelevant in this case. The *presentation* will be different, but the result will be just the same as OP's `to_char(col_date, 'mon-yyyy')`.

Comment: Yes..Right!! in my case issue was in oracle query. Query from date to <= date not returning last date data. So I have added < next date to solve.